# nullPointer exception when trying to access adapter after asynctask refresh

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I was following along with some videos on making a weather app and somehow ended up trying to launch my `AsyncTask` from a button pressed in a drop down from my actionbar. Right now the asynctask is a separate class and the application loads the aynctask fine the first time but when i try to refresh and re launch the async task from a button in my actionbar menu the app crashes with a `NullPointerException` :

```
07-18 00:45:05.615    5849-5849/johnpark.sunshine E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at johnpark.sunshine.MainActivityFragment.processFinish(MainActivityFragment.java:70)
            at johnpark.sunshine.ForeCastLoader.onPostExecute(ForeCastLoader.java:39)
            at johnpark.sunshine.ForeCastLoader.onPostExecute(ForeCastLoader.java:23)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Its getting a nullPointer exception when trying to access the adapter again. Essentially there is a refresh button in my drop down in my Main activity that extends ActionBar. When i click that button it calls a method from the `MainActivityFragment` class that calls the execute method of the `ForeCastLoader asynctask`. In the `onPostExecute()` method the results are passed back to the fragment through a `processFinish()` method. Back in that method in ActivityFragment, when trying to use the adapter i get a null pointer exception. Any ideas as to what im doing wrong?

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
                implements OnNavigationListener, android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
private boolean mNaviFirstHit = true;
MainActivityFragment mfa;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] dropdownValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_list);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(actionBar.getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, android.R.id.text1,
            dropdownValues);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
    if (mNaviFirstHit) {
        mNaviFirstHit = false;
        return true;
    }

    if(position==1)
    {
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }
    if(position==2)
    {
        mfa = new MainActivityFragment();
        mfa.update();
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

MainActivityFragment

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment implements AsyncResponse{

private ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList<>();
static ListView lv;
ForeCastLoader  f = new ForeCastLoader(); 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
    f.delegate = this;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.list_item_forecast,
            R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, list);

    f.execute("94043");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    lv = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), DetailView.class);
            in.putExtra("tempData", adapter.getItem(position));
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}

public void update()
{
    f.delegate = this;
    f.execute("97865");
}

public void processFinish(String[] output)
{
    list.clear();
    for(String s:output)
    {
        list.add(s);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I left out the aSyncTask class because i already know its returning values correctly and i dont think the problem could be anywhere there. 
Thanks for your help, im sure its something im just overlooking.

Comment: Well you must be following Udacity tutorial ,I got same error  and can't figured it out , I solved this by removing MainActivityFragment and doing everything in MainActivity.java

Comment: haha yup, the thing is i know i could do it that way but now that ive gotten to this point i want to get this going.

Comment: Well please do tell me the solution and a piece of advice upcoming lesson in that course sucks :D

Comment: You dont have to call **setAdapter()** after calling **notifyDataSetChanged()**

Comment: Yeah  i didnt think i needed it i just did that as an extra fallback to see if it would help, the app still crashes before it reaches that line again though anyways.

Comment: Do you recreate the `AsyncTask` every time you call `execute` on it? If not, that's why it's crashing. After a `Thread` runs you have to create a new one to run it again.

Comment: ForeCastLoader is the aSyncTask class. Its a global variable in MainActivityFragment that gets instantiated when MainActivityFragment is created. A new MainActivityFragment is created each time the update button is pushed from the ActionBar so I feel like that is creating a new aSyncTask each time...

Comment: at which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: at the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in the processFinish() method in MainActivityFragment. Works the first time the app loads, does not work when i click the refresh button in the ActionBar of MainActivity

Comment: On click on update, are you calling onNavigationItemSelected in MainActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can see you create a new `MainActivityFragment` when the NavigationItem clicked. In this way the newly created `MainActivityFragment` is not the one that you added to your `MainActivity` when you first launch the app. The new one's `onCreate` method is not called, so you can't access the `adapter` in it.

The right way to access a previously added `Fragment` in an `Activity` is to use the `findFragmentByTag` method of the `FragmentManager`.

I assume you add your `MainActivityFragment` with a tag like this.

```
transaction.add(id, maf, MainActivityFragmentTag);
```

After adding it, you can access it like this.

```
if(position==2)
{
    mfa = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MainActivityFragmentTag);
    mfa.update();
}
```

Comment: This did it. I had to create a new aSyncTask class with every refresh click too but its refreshing with new data now no problem. Thank you so much, You are a genius and I need to study Fragments some more.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the refresh button, I assume you are calling the `onNavigationItemSelected()` method in `MainActivity` with `position =2`.Inside the if condition, you are creating a new instance of `MainActivityFragment` and calling it's `update()` method.But your adapter is getting initialised in `createView()` method in `MainActivityFragment` and it wont be called since you haven't called `show()` on this new fragment instance.Try calling `update()` method on the existing fragment itself.